# Prevent logging in without password

Tags: 16.04, login, password, login-screen

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system the normal unity desktop is installed. There are 2 users, my admin account with password, and the standard account for my child with password. Initially it was configured to login automatically to my child's account. I've disabled this option, but still can login without having to enter the child account's password. I want my child to require to enter the password before being logged in.

What steps I need to do to investigate and finally fix the problem?

Comment: Did you restart after making changes ?

Comment: If the reboot did not change anything, maybe the child account is still a member of the `nopasswdlogin` group. Please log in as the child and run the terminal command `groups` to list all groups the account is a member of.

Comment: @ByteCommander: yes, this is the case. Would you like to turn it into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed by examining the output of the command `groups` while being logged in as the child, its account is still a member of the `nopasswdlogin` group.

You can manually remove the group membership `nopasswdlogin` from a user by running the command below from an admin account:

```
sudo deluser <child-account> nopasswdlogin
```